# Not able to receive large list in struts 2

Tags: struts2, struts, ognl

I have a form with 10,000 plus check boxes with each check box have a numeric value like 8757857,8755854. When I submit the form i can see the whole data is going correctly to the backend in the network but if I check in my action class I get less values (only receiving somewhere around 9900 records).

I have tried receiving it in a List and String in the Action, but its same for both.

I have tried this issue in 3 machines and the same thing is happening.

I want to know whether it's struts 2 or any other struts 2 interceptor which is truncating the values?

Comment: Are you submitted the form using `GET` or `POST`?  If you're using `GET`, chances are you've reached the maximum HTTP Request URI length and why you're seeing truncation.  Changing to `POST` should resolve the issue.

Comment: I am already using POST.

Comment: Could you please post the code you're using?

Answer (score -1):

Paaji, Try looking into code of Check box Interceptor in Struts2. Might be you get something there.

Comment: I have checked the checkbox interceptor and found that the interceptor is putting all the values in a Hashmap. So I am thinking values might be colliding inside hashmap. I will have to make a custom interceptor for that. Let me try it and come back.

Comment: i have debugged the checkedbox interceptor class. I get a string[] for checked boxes. There only i am getting lesser checked values.

Comment: @SunnyChhatwal When you finished post the code to the question.

Comment: Please share more details about how to resolve the problem